# Unable to create Rails Project in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-mavericks, rubymine, rubymine-7

I have RubyMine V 7.1.4.
All gems and Ruby installed on my machine through rbenv and homebrew.
I can create and run rails on my console, but on RubyMine I am unable to create a project. RubyMine does not list the rails which is installed on my machine.
If I click on "Install Rails Gem...", it gives me a list of gems, but after the installation, rails is still not listed:
[image]

[image]

I tried to open existing Rails project with RubyMine, but I am unable to run it. I am getting "No rails found on SDK" error:
[image]

However, rails is there:
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: My list of Ruby SDKs in RM9 reflects what is loaded on my machine. I am not sure that RubyMine7 has it, but in the dropdown list (on the project creation screen) there are places for me to add a Ruby SDK. You may also want to set up your preferences and then restart RM to see it the creation wizard will pick them up.

Comment: rubymine suppports Rails 5 since v 2016.1

Comment: What about rails 4? I have it installed as well